# Return a Data Frame with Only the Max Values

Tags: r, dataframe, max

Say I have this data frame, lesson, with 3 columns (`User`, `Course`, `Score`), which looks something like:

> User Course Score

```
  A   1.1     9
  A   1.1     8         
  B   1.2     7
```

Only it has a lot more data. If I want to get a data frame that only has the highest scores for each course by each user, how would I go about doing that?
I tried:

```
lesson<-lesson[order(lesson$User,lesson$Course,-lesson$User),]
```

and then

```
lesson[!duplicated(lesson$User && lesson$Course),]
```

but I got an error back.

Answer (score 3):

```
DF <-  read.table(text="User Course Score
A   1.1     9
A   1.1     8
B   1.1     1
B   1.2     7",header=TRUE)

aggregate(Score~Course*User,data=DF,FUN=max)

#  Course User Score
#1    1.1    A     9
#2    1.1    B     1
#3    1.2    B     7
```

Comment: The document is a csv, that I have already imported, so I'm assuming the formulas changes? because I got an error

Comment: "I got an error" is not really helpful. There is a reason for error messages, you know?

Comment: It says, "Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : cannot coerce class "formula" into a data.frame"

Comment: i did: aggregate(lesson$Score~lesson$Course*lesson$User,data=lesson,FUN=max)

Comment: @user2543427 If you specify `data=lesson`, you don't need to do `lesson$` for all your variables.

Answer (score 0):

or you might want to try plyr package

```
library(plyr)
ddply(DF,.(User,Course),transform,maxScore=max(Score,na.rm=TRUE))

User Course Score maxScore
 A    1.1     9        9
 A    1.1     8        9
 B    1.1     1        1
 B    1.2     7        7
```

or if you want to see the max score only

```
ddply(DF,.(User,Course),summarise,maxScore=max(Score,na.rm=TRUE))

User Course maxScore
 A    1.1        9
 B    1.1        1
 B    1.2        7
```